# "Is this what you want" - answers

Tags: discussion

On posts with an unclear question or question which does not contain enough information to diagnose the problem.

Users posts comments asking for clarification.

One totally assumes what the OP might be looking for and posts something related asking

*is this what you want*

or

*is this what you what you're looking for?*

Is *"Is this what you want"* answer an answer? It's obvious that whoever posted the answer haven't understood the question clearly, yet.

What do you usually do about such answers?

Comment: It's still an answer; but if you have the rep is vote to close the question. It's obviously unclear what is being asked...

Comment: Bad questions inevitably produce bad answers.  Getting the question closed *quickly* is important to stop that from happening.

Comment: Its an attempt to answer, sure. It's just not useful.

Comment: @Deduplicator hence i asked *What do you usually do about such answers..* :) not sure what is the right thing to do..

Comment: Unless the answer is provably wrong, I'd simply leave it as is. It's not worth upvoting but neither provably downvote-worthy, so it's a zero-sum game. Not what we want, but nothing wrong with it per se either. If the question eventually gets closed anyway, it doesn't matter one way or the other. And if it's actually right, good on the poster.

Comment: @deceze *"Unless the answer is provably wrong"* - that's the problem... even the answerer doesn't know whether it's right or wrong... in most of the cases this can be avoided by asking clarification by a comment rather than blindly posting something as answer...

Comment: I have the feeling that sometimes these answers help the op to clearify the question.

Comment: A comment asking *"are you trying to do this"?* will help the OP clarify the question as well, IMHO. I was tempted to ask this question when i saw a well reputed member asked OP is this what you want in comments with a demo, later someone posted the same as an answer.. isn't it just noise?

Comment: [Whoops](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25823353/1993402), I did the same thing yesterday. I add this or something like `May that help you?` at the end of my answers, if I'm not 100% (but 80-90%) sure to understand what the OP is asking for, because sometimes it is too easy like in the referenced question, where I was really confused that he couldn't do this by himself! I do so as I hope that the OP will clarify himself by some comment feedback to know it was a successful answer (he did so by accepting the answer). But I'm not happy with the answer, too. So are you talking about answers like that?

Comment: @ConcurrentHashMap No, i wouldn't call it an unclear question. It's clear what he wants to do - trigger a function when y coordinate of  mouse is greater than 20. If it was an unclear question, surely there'll be comments, downvotes, close votes... ;)

Comment: I sometimes weigh it up based on the likelihood of the OP responding to a comment in a timely manner vs the time it would take to type an answer (if I think I know what they are after). Nothing worse than hanging round for a response and it not coming.

Answer (score 5):

> On posts with an unclear question or question which does not contain
>   enough information to diagnose the problem.

As we all agreed, this kind of questions should downvoted and [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) as *unclear what you're asking*. People continue the asking bad questions if we won't stop answering them.

> is this what you want
>
> or
>
> is this what you what you're looking for?
>
> Is "Is this what you want" answer an answer?

Answers should be formed as an answer and questions should be formed as a question. Not vice versa.

Let's say someone posted "Have you tried Fooing the Bar" as an answer. But this can simply say "Foo the Bar". In such a case, rather than flagging as "not an answer" (because it *is*) **you can edit it yourself or post a comment on that answer asking to OP refactor his answer from question into the statement**.

> It's obvious that whoever posted the answer haven't understood the
>   question clearly, yet.

*Well*, I'm not sure posting an answer in a question form means that user didn't understand the question clearly. People could write this kind of formatted answers even if they clearly understand the question.

We often see these kinds of answers when there are several possible solutions. And sometimes people may feel weird offering a directive answer in case where they know that there are several possible solutions. *In fact*, this has the same weirdness as much as giving an answer in a question form in our community in my opinion.

Comment: +1 because I think I have sometimes posted answers that have started "Is this what you are looking for", but I do not think this is because I have not understood the question.  It is just a way of making my answer seem more polite. If this is deemed to be bad then I would much rather get a comment that says "refactor this answer into a statement" rather than a "not an answer" flag.

Answer (score 3):

**Tl;dr Leave them be.**

There is always some guesswork involved in answering. A blatant syntactical error? Oops turns out OP merely mistyped the relevant bit of code, underlying issue still stands. A working Excel formula solution? Ah- but OP actually required a VBA solution, though did not tag as such. Works perfectly in Windows? Er, OP forgot to mention this was for a Mac. Date value 1/1/1900? Except it turns out it is a string, and so on and so on and so on.

Without knowing the solution, OPs struggle to provide the relevant information. Anyone who is absolutely certain they know what the right answer is, probably is blinkered to the nuances of interpretation and the potential subtleties of the question.

You yourself have “You might want to move your script ... if it is not already in it.” and “If you simply want to ...” [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22249361/1505120)

“here's something to start with ...:”[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22270214/1505120)

“try this ...”[3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22255521/1505120)

“assuming what you want to do is ...”[4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22063701/1505120)

*“Is this what you want”* is just a slightly different way of expressing uncertainty equivalent to the above.

Comment: I was talking more about [answers like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11927618/2333214). BTW,  2 and 3 doesn't belong to this category. 
P.S: i never said i haven't done this before. I'm asking the general opinion.

Comment: *The above was not to call you a hypocrite* - Feel free to do so.. If you dig deeper there might be more like those... never found time for a cleanup.. :D

Answer (score 1):

> Is "Is this what you want" answer an answer? It's obvious that whoever
>   posted the answer haven't understood the question clearly, yet.

If I come across this kind of an answer, I immediately look a the question because it definitely needs a downvote, maybe even a vote to be closed because its not clear and obvious.  Then I have a look at the answer and if its very terse, then I might flag it as a non-answer.

To remedy this, I would usually start the answer with the following:

"It is not clear what you are asking, but I think what you want is ..."

Then further describe the solution and why it would fit the situation.  If you are lucky, the user might realize it and then edit the question to make it obvious what they are after.  I recently had to do exactly this [for a very poorly worded question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757756/how-can-i-create-a-two-step-form-or-wizard-where-the-model-has-a-foreign-key-b/25758339#25758339), and was greeted with [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757756/how-can-i-create-a-two-step-form-or-wizard-where-the-model-has-a-foreign-key-b/25758339#comment40279454_25758339) from the OP, although it didn't save them the two downvotes:

> i will try this, i gonna change my title first, ...

The bottom line is **answers are only as good as questions** - so the priority should be to fix the question so that it will solicit good answers, rather punish someone that is trying to help.

Comment: I think there is not such a big difference between "I think what you want is.." and "Is this what you want". Both essential conveys the same idea.

Comment: Your bolded phrase is quite right, although I disagree with your conclusion.  Regardless of the fact that they were trying to help, *they weren't actually helping* and their answer is of very low value precisely because they posted it to an unclear question that even they couldn't understand.  Not only should you focus on improving the question, but so should that poster, rather than posting a low quality answer.

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is:

- A user is asking a question that is interesting and useful.
- It's somewhat unclear regarding details of the users use case.
- The user is not available for clarifications.

What makes the question interesting and useful is some aspect that can be applied in a general way.

The **value for other users** in the answers is based on the general aspect.
The exact question of the user is not clear, but also it is mainly **relevant to himself**.

In this situation, giving an answer that may miss the (unclear) problem details, but covers the interesting high level part makes sense, I think.

What I do, instead of asking *"Is this what you what you're looking for?"* is to

**state the assumptions I made**
 (and encourage a new user to provide input so I can adapt the answer to his use case).

The answer aims to be useful for users arriving by a seach matching the question. Adapting it to the needs of the user is an **optional second step**. All this assuming he is unavailable for feedback at the time of writing, and there are enough comments on the question requesting clarification.

The risk with this is that a closed, or low voted question could make a good answer less accessible.

Answer (score -1):

If I come across answers like that, I take a view of just how much guess-work has been involved. If I feel a small gap has been bridged by a clearly stated assumption, I leave them alone. I don't up-vote them  unless I'm pretty confident the original problem is now solved.

If a larger assumption has been made, I tend to at least comment on the answer, asking why further clarification wasn't sought. In some cases, when rep-whoring feels pretty likely, I'll down-vote. The down-vote is more likely when a higher rep user has done this (as I feel they should know better).

In both cases, naturally I'll be down-voting and/or voting to close the question, since it's unclear.

I've answered questions in this manner in the past, and looking back now I think I regret it almost every time I have. It nearly always spawns a long comment thread underneath and triggers a chameleon answer. It also rewards people who post rubbish questions with my time and effort, which doesn't seem right.

Answer (score -19):

If the answer is of good quality, and in the same time the question is badly written and unclear, the solution that would add the most value to the community may be to **edit the question** so that it matches the answer.

While it may be controversial, and it may be againts OPs intention, it will give the community the valuable answer to some problem.

If the answer is pure guessing, and it doesn't bring anything special, the best is to downvote/close/delete the question.

Comment: We don't fit questions to solutions. The only precedent you could possibly be taking this from is to ask and answer your own question, but the GOAL should be to provide complete answers to well-written questions, not write-well the question that leads to a complete solution.